# Пробелы при адаптивной в хэдере и футере

Tags: css3

не могу понять как убрать пробелы, отмеченные красным,можете помочь разобраться? Вот исходный код http://www.cssdesk.com/J8Xk9

[image: сайт]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас div.menubar выезжает за границу из-за padding-left: 13%;

Comment: убрав паддинг все стало ок,а что делать с футером?

Comment: посмотри какой блок еще вылазит за границу, если не сможешь найти то пиши

Comment: посмотрел,увы не нашел...помоги,пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Переверстать сайт.
Верстка просто ужасная

```
min-width: 1200px;
```

Убрать, отступы это нормально, вы сами задали:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

А скролл горизонтальный и собственно сами отступы появляются из-за того, что тело сайта не изменяется при изменении ширины экрана.